# Pass more params from devise registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

From the`views/plans/new.html.erb` I get the plan_id and price params with the following:

```
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_store_registration_path(:plan_id => plan.id, :price => plan.price) %>
```

Then the app redirects to the sign-up page and with the methods `def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)` and `def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` I keep the previous params and merge the email param:

registrations_controller.rb

```
class Stores::RegistrationsController <  Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   def new
     build_resource({})
     resource.build_account
     respond_with self.resource
     session[:registration_params] = request.query_parameters
   end


   def create
     build_resource(sign_up_params)
     resource.save
     yield resource if block_given?
     if resource.persisted?
       if resource.active_for_authentication?
         flash[:notice] = 'Successfully signed up'
         respond_with resource, location:   after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       else
         flash[:notice] = "Signed up but #{resource.inactive_message}"
     expire_data_after_sign_in!
     respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       end
     else
       clean_up_passwords resource
       set_minimum_password_length
       respond_with resource
     end
   end


   def edit
     super
   end


   def update
     super
   end


    def destroy
     super
    end

    def cancel
     super
    end

  protected

   def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u|
      u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
           :account_attributes => [:first_name, :last_name, :buisness_name,
                                   :buisness_description, :web_site, :phone_number,
                                   :street, :city, :state, :zip_code, :country])
    }
  end


  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     new_transaction_path(resource,  session[:registration_params].merge(ema‌​il: resource.email))
  end

   def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     new_transaction_path(resource, session[:registration_params].merge(ema‌​il: resource.email))
   end
end
```

After submit sign-up, the app redirects to the views/transcation/new.html.erb, which has the `plan_id`, `price`and `email` params.

```
 Parameters: {"ema‌​il"=>"example@gmail.com", "plan_id"=>"bs96", "price"=>"150.0"}
```

And the url shows:

```
http://localhost:3000/transactions/new.1?ema%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bil=example%40gmail.com&plan_id=bs96&price=150.0
```

Inside the views/transcation/new.html.erb there is the braintree drop in ui and the script along with the three hidden fields:

```
<div class="form-container radius-box glassy-bg small-10 small-centered medium-8 large-6 columns">
  <%= form_tag transactions_path do%>
      <div id="dropin"></div>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:email, params["email"]) %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:plan_id, params["plan_id"]) %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:amount, params["price"]) %>
      <%=submit_tag "Pay #{params["price"]}$", class: "button mt1" %>
  <%end%>
</div>

<script>
    braintree.setup("<%=@client_token%>", 'dropin', {
        container: 'dropin'
    });
</script>
```

At this point I'm trying to keep the email param to the transaction with
`<%= hidden_field_tag(:email, params["email"]) %>`

But if I click submit i'm not getting an email as you can see in the following:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KeS2xK7NIJZwFQvW2kJKupcpURnQweq+yoRgk9AJ1aaOgFIIym4RKadI4jc6vYynMo4vKR4eLmdIynfBG+EusQ==", "email"=>"", "plan_id"=>"bs96", "amount"=>"150.0", "payment_method_nonce"=>"0c22f2fa-e212-0ad3-753b-0d183d02522b"}
```

If I inspect the params inside the views/transcation/new.html.erb with this     `<%= params.inspect %>` it prints out this: `<ActionController::Parameters {"ema‌​il"=>"example@gmail.com", "plan_id"=>"bs96", "price"=>"150.0", "controller"=>"transactions", "action"=>"new"} permitted: false>`

And this `<%= params[:email].inspect %>` returns `nil`

Any ideas why I can't get the email param?

**Update 1**

After I click on the link sign-up:

```
   Started GET "/stores/sign_up?plan_id=bs96&price=150.0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-10 13:46:23 +0300
Processing by Stores::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"plan_id"=>"bs96", "price"=>"150.0"}
  Rendering stores/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered stores/shared/_links.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered stores/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (14.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 110ms (Views: 46.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

After submit sign-up:

```
  Started POST "/stores" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-10 13:47:07 +0300
Processing by Stores::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"A65CebXfvIw14X7tnOYrrtjfbB3uZzMtcbmd2IFc91yKt8KSyKToJt2kIl3xyV6AK9HVfQrXFpLG9RPtrvUOrw==", "store"=>{"email"=>"example@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "account_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"david", "last_name"=>"davisp", "buisness_name"=>"1", "buisness_description"=>"1", "web_site"=>"1", "phone_number"=>"1", "street"=>"1", "city"=>"1", "state"=>"1", "zip_code"=>"1", "country"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Store Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "example@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "stores" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["email", "example@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$DN/K2dBlo4DzoVf9uMlD9uo8iKYp14ROT8w3eR9Tt8fD7B1ksdvt."], ["created_at", "2017-08-10 10:47:07.920623"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-10 10:47:07.920623"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "accounts" ("buisness_name", "buisness_description", "web_site", "phone_number", "street", "zip_code", "country", "first_name", "last_name", "created_at", "updated_at", "store_id", "city", "state") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["buisness_name", "1"], ["buisness_description", "1"], ["web_site", "1"], ["phone_number", "1"], ["street", "1"], ["zip_code", "1"], ["country", "1"], ["first_name", "david"], ["last_name", "davisp"], ["created_at", "2017-08-10 10:47:07.922113"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-10 10:47:07.922113"], ["store_id", 1], ["city", "1"], ["state", "1"]]
   (10.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/transactions/new.1?ema%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bil=example%40gmail.com&plan_id=bs96&price=150.0
 Completed 302 Found in 161ms (ActiveRecord: 10.7ms)
```

Redirected to views/plans/new.html.erb :

```
   Started GET "/transactions/new.1?ema%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bil=example%40gmail.com&plan_id=bs96&price=150.0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-10 13:47:07 +0300
Processing by TransactionsController#new as 
  Parameters: {"ema‌​il"=>"example@gmail.com", "plan_id"=>"bs96", "price"=>"150.0"}
  Rendering transactions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered transactions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1106ms (Views: 42.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Finally if I click pay on views/plans/new.html.erb :

```
Started POST "/transactions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-10 13:47:24 +0300
Processing by TransactionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x/FWkCSqla3ugmaOgP79RySg6HMpafZel5ddl7nzIRZO6NZ7Wd HBBwbHOj7t0Yhp165RE83Z0+Eg29OillrY5Q==", "email"=>"", "plan_id"=>"bs96", "amount"=>"150.0", "payment_method_nonce"=>"fb99a62a-025d-0283-5932-fb3a297cc0e9"}
898559083
8yx4w8
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 2535ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: What is `resource`? Presumably the user that just signed up, right? Just pass that as a parameter, or only `resource.email` (/whatever) if you prefer.

Comment: It may even make sense for the transactions to be resourced within the users - i.e. `new_user_transaction_path(resource, session[:registration_params])`

Comment: Thank for the reply @Tom Lord.... hmmmm pass the resources.email parameter how and where?

Comment: If you're just going to use a plain hash of parameters, then just add to it: `new_transaction_path(session[:registration_params].merge(email: resource.email))`

Comment: Thanks @Tom Lord!!! And if I want to access the email params : `<%= hidden_field_tag(:email, params["email"]) %>` ???

Comment: Yes, that would work. Although to be honest, I'm a but confused why you are doing this... Can a user ever create a transaction for any user *other than themselves*? If not, then why do you even need to pass the email as a parameter? You can just reference `current_user.email` in the `TransactionsController` - thereby also mitigating security risks.

Comment: The user is not logged in at the time I'm trying to pass the transaction, so I can't really use the `current_user.email`...I need the user to complete the payment and then login. If you find a way around this then please let me know, thanks!

Comment: @Tom Lord, if I use the merge as you suggested the email param does appear in the console after registration... but when I get redirected to the transaction page and do this `<%= params["email"].inspect %>` it comes out nil... any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Not without seeing more context of the code. Check exactly what path is being taken; perhaps you're signing **in** rather than signing **up** - and therefore going through a different code path? However, this brings me back to the original point: Why pass this as a parameter at all? Just use `current_user.email` (if signed in).

Comment: Thanks for the help @Tom Lord, I just updated the whole question, please take a look if you'd like. And if you need any more code please let me know! I have been trying to fix this bug for a while now!!

Comment: I can't use current_user because the whole process is: buy a subscription plan, create a customer with the email at Braintree, and when user trip to login check if subscription is active and allow login!

Comment: Let me get this straight: `params = ActionController::Parameters {"ema‌​il"=>"example@gmail.com", ...}`, but `params[:email] == nil`??!! That's not possible.

Comment: Also, why does your code line above say `"email"=>""`? That's inconsistent with what you write next.

Comment: Also, why is the URL parameter: `ema%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bil=example`? Did you copy+paste some hidden characters into a text editor? `%E2%80%8C` means `⁌`, and `%E2%80%8B` means `⁋` ([source](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)), which makes me think you've got some hidden whitespace chars in the text editor.

Comment: Please check the update 1... the exact code I have above returns the exact results I have in update1... its weird that the email is showing nil, maybe I'm missing something that I can't see. But it should be working!!

Comment: Again: The only weird thing I can see is that `ema%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bil` parameter. Check exactly what you have saved here: `new_transaction_path(resource,  session[:registration_params].merge(ema‌​il: resource.email))`. Also, you only need to write: `new_transaction_path(session[:registration_params].merge(ema‌​il: resource.email))`

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's two hidden characters in your text editor, between the `a` and `i` in `email`.

Comment: I has some some hidden whitespace characters in the `new_transaction_path(session[:registration_params].merge(email:resource.email))`... I had to retype this line and it worked!!! Thanks for the pointers @Tom Lord I appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has some some hidden whitespace characters in the `new_transaction_path(session[:registration_params].merge(email:resource.email))`... I had to retype this line and it worked!!!